# Global temp tables with SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

In SSMS, I can create a global temp variable in one batch and use it in another. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ##temp (col1 INT)
GO

DROP TABLE ##temp
GO
```

With SQLCMD, I create a global temp table in one call and it does not exist in the second.

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -d tempdb -E -Q "create table ##temp (col1 int)"

sqlcmd -S localhost -d tempdb -E -Q "drop table ##temp"
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Server VATLLXT7LGBARE2, Line 1
Cannot drop the table '##temp', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Is a global temp table not supposed to stick around until the server is reset?

Comment: It sticks around until you, or whoever uses it last, disconnects. SSMS is different because the connection is typically persisted while the query editor is open; SQLCMD is connecting and disconnecting on each invocation.

Comment: It is also possible to create normal tables into tempdb, and those are not dropped automatically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that's correct cause global temporary table exists in the connection/session that created it and gets dropped automatically if the connection closes. In your case, first `SQLCMD` creates the table

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -d tempdb -E -Q "create table ##temp (col1 int)"
```

And the connection closes which drops the temporary table and so in next connection it doesn't exists anymore

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -d tempdb -E -Q "drop table ##temp"
```

Comment: "if the connection closes" [and if no one else use this table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399(v=sql.105).aspx)